# Make flex item full width after it's been wrapped without using media queries

Tags: css, flexbox

Using flexbox here. Is it possible to make overlapping element full width after it has been pushed down without media queries?

See attached plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/mxACfJ2VR5yNgP9j8WJh?p=preview

Resize preview window to less than 425px width. Third element gets pushed down and then I want to make it full width. When it is in the same line as other 2 elements it must not grow.

```css
.flexContainer {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  border: 1px solid;
}

.img {
  width: 110px;
  height: 110px;
  background: red;
}

.flexItem {
  flex-basis: 200px;
  flex-grow: 1;
  background: #ff1;
}

.wrapItem {
  flex-basis: 100px;
  background: #aab;
}
```

```html
<div class="flexContainer">
  <div class="img">fixed size img here</div>
  <div class="flexItem">This flexes</div>
  <div class="wrapItem">This wraps</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Without a media query the flex item doesn't know that it's wrapping. It doesn't know anything beyond the original code. So why would it change on wrap? I believe the answer to your question is no.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can not do that. But you can get pretty close.

Just set the grow on the flex item to a huge value (9999) and grow on the wrap item to 1

```css
 .flexContainer {
    display:flex;
    flex-wrap:wrap;
    border: 1px solid;
  }
  .img {
    width:110px;
    height:110px;
    background:red;
  }
  .flexItem {
    flex-basis:200px;
    flex-grow:9999;
    background:#ff1;
  }
  .wrapItem {
    flex-basis:100px;
    flex-grow:1;
    background:#aab;
  }
```

```html
  <body>
    <div class="flexContainer">
      <div class="img">fixed size img here</div>
      <div class="flexItem">This flexes</div>
      <div class="wrapItem">This wraps</div>
    </div>
  </body>
```

Comment: Nice! :) Maybe I am missing something, but to me it looks not pretty close, but exactly what I wanted. Thanks! Like those little css hacks :)

Comment: Well, when flexItem is growing, wrapItem is also growing (your request was that it shouldn't grow. But, for every 10000 pixels available, one takes 9999 and the other takes 1. So the size of wrapItem would eventually go from 100px to 101px (In very large screens)

Comment: The `flex-grow` is actually the growth speed of the element relative to the rest of the elements. An element with `flex-grow: 5` grows 5x faster than an element with `flex-grow: 1`.

Answer (score 6):

You haven't told that element that it is allowed to grow by adding `flex-grow:1`

```css
.flexContainer {
    display:flex;
    flex-wrap:wrap;
    border: 1px solid;
}
.img {
    width:110px;
    height:110px;
    background:red;
}
.flexItem {
    flex-basis:200px;
    flex-grow:1;
    background:#ff1;
}
.wrapItem {
    flex-grow:1;
    flex-basis:100px;
    background:#aab;
}
```

```html
<div class="flexContainer">
    <div class="img">fixed size img here</div>
    <div class="flexItem">This flexes</div>
    <div class="wrapItem">This wraps</div>
</div>
```

[**JSfiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/gLjoLrys/)

Comment: The question says: *When it is in the same line as other 2 elements it must not grow.* ... When you add `flex-grow: 1` the `.wrapItem` grows when the screen expands, even when on the same line as its siblings.